# Everything but this is getting translated with localized

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I've been working on translating my application to different languages today, but somehow I'm getting a strange problem. No errors, no warnings.

I've translated the whole application (A lot of buttons, navigation buttons, labels etc etc) But somehow, this three buttons is not getting translated, haha.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    translateCode()
}

//Translating the language
func translateCode()
{
    //This one works fine
    header.title = NSLocalizedString("settingsHeader", comment: "")
    history.text = NSLocalizedString("settingsHistory", comment: "")
    dogpass.text = NSLocalizedString("settingsDogpass", comment: "")
    settings.text = NSLocalizedString("settingsSettings", comment: "")

    //This is not getting translated
    profileBtn.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("profile1", comment: ""), for: .normal)
    cpBtn.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("changePass1", comment: ""), for: .normal)
    cdpBtn.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("change1", comment: ""), for: .normal)

    //This one works fine
    btn_logout.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("logout", comment: ""), for: .normal)
}
```

Inside the Localizable string

```
//SettingsViewController
"settingsHeader" = "Inställningar";
"settingsHistory" = "Historik";
"settingsDogpass" = "Hundpass";
"settingsSettings" = "Inställningar";
"profile1" = "Min profil";
"changePass1" = "Ändra lösenord";
"change1" = "Ändra hund / person";
"logout" = "Logga ut";
```

The storyboard is written in English.
And when I run the application the button text is still written in English.

To be more clear:

[image: It is connected]

What I've tried:

- Removed the connection and re-added it.
- Changed the name of the key.
- Re-wrote the code for the buttons.

So everything is getting translated, but this! Whyyyyy?

Comment: try deleting derived data.

Comment: Missing infos: Is `NSLocalizedString("profile1", comment: "")` returning the correct value? If not, maybe check if there is an invisible character. Remove even the double quotes, write the key even manually instead of a copy/paste. Do you set somewhere else `profileBtn.setTitle()`? Or `profileBtn.title = `?

Comment: @Larme I don’t set it in any other place. I did wrote it manually. And for the last, it’s like my 40th button i’m doing this on, and every other works just as fine. But somehow this isnt, haha! I’ve compared it with the rest but it looks equally. I’m confused. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the title from attributed to plain. Thanks for the help of yours!

[image: plain]